# How to parse JSON string with unescaped properties in Node.js ES6

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, ecmascript-6

I have following String that contains JSON with unescaped properties and I want to parse it in Node.js/ES6:

```
const A="{prop1=null, prop2=SOME-VALUE, prop3=[{prop4=2018-04-13T19:07:47.008Z}]}"
```

How to parse it correctly, or is there some JSON parser that is safer then JSON.parse, because:

```
JSON.parse("{prop1=null, prop2=SOME-VALUE, prop3=[{prop4=2018-04-13T19:07:47.008Z}]}")
```

is throwing an error:

```
VM2683:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

**update:**

That's **not valid JSON** taken from an external system and I would like to parse it anyway with some parser that might work with the content like that, or the way (lib) to escape it making it a valid JSON to use JSON.parse after

Comment: This is not JSON. Where did you get this from?

Comment: This is not JSON, you may need to manually parse out the content between = and , if you are unable to get this in JSON

Comment: const A is literally a string...

Comment: What is the actual format? What is the external system, and what does it expect you to do with this data?

Comment: I'm not posting it as an answer since it's hacky and likely to fail, but here is the beginning of an attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/gmvns4ms/

Answer (score 1):

This is not JSON and no JSON parser is going to be able to handle it:

- JSON separates keys from values with a colon, not an equals sign
- JSON keys and values that are strings must be surrounded by quotes ""

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous libraries that are capable of parsing invalid JSON in loose manner, e.g. [`loose-json`](https://github.com/ssnau/loose-json). The problem is that this string is **not JSON**. Since the string is not valid JS, it can't be evaluated either.

The string cannot be process with regular `replace` because it follows certain syntax, e.g. `=` delimiter could be replaced with `:` as a step towards JSON, but values that contain `=` character shouldn't be affected. The string should be tokenized first and processed according to expected syntax.

Some libraries may be helpful for tokenization, like `esprima` (`esprima.tokenize()`), but a lot of work on inconsistencies has to be done, depending on particular file format:

- there is `null` property value, how should the parser decide if it's `null` or `'null'` string?
- property values aren't wrapped with quotes, how should whitespaces be treated?
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update, you will need to write a custom string parser that will transform the source into some valid JSON string, then use `JSON.parse()` - or you can even ignore the `JSON.parse` method and directly create the object if you want (that would be a pain tho).

You can use Regex or any string manipulation methods to  [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for example the `=` into `:`, etc...